# Stop OneSignal notification to display in status bar

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I have implemented **OneSignal** and successfully sending notification to my android app, but I want to discard some  notification based on additional data received in push notification. How can I discard notification before displaying in status bar.

Answer (score 4):

To do so create a class which extends `NotificationExtenderService`,

In this

```
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;

public class NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample extends NotificationExtenderService {
   @Override
   protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationPayload notification) {
      // Read any properties you need from notification.
      // Return true if you want to keep a notification from displaying else return false if you dont want to display notification.
      return false;
   }
}
```

Also when sending notification from panel check the Background data checkbox

And edit your manifest file to include this:-

```
<service
   android:name=".YOUR_CLASS_NAME"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I have already implemented this class and returning false also display notification on  status bar.

Comment: Which sdk version you are using ?

Comment: I already added this and processed my notification based on additional data but I want to discard notification when some error occur due to wrong param in additional data or param missing, But my notification is always displaying in status bar even some additional data missing in app getting exception  in background. I am returning false in case of exception.

Comment: If sending notification using Rest Api then dont put anything in "contents":"",
If sending through panel then dont type anything in message content

Comment: Return `true` from `onNotificationProcessing` to count the notification as processed. It won't be displayed then. You no longer need to set the `Background data` option as this is for an older undocumented and deprecated method. Recommend using the latest 2.5.0 SDK just in case.

Comment: Currently I am sending  via dashboard.

Comment: dont type anything in Message Content and then send and see if it still displays notification

Comment: @VishnuPrasad I have tried with message and content empty with enable background data but still message is displaying. It will not send notification if content field is empty.

Comment: @jkasten I am using `compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'` for onesignal dependency as given on docs and it is downloading and using 2.4.3 SDK.

Comment: @ved Current version was just updated to 2.5.1 today. You may need to restart Android Studio and/or go to `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle file`.

Comment: Return true to stop the notification from displaying